# How to fix code not returning e-mail addresses

Tags: google-apps-script

I posted a question earlier on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56850586/how-to-fix-null-fields-in-google-apps-script-e-mail-lookup) helping me out with some code for a rota sheet I'm working on.

It was working. But now for some reason it isn't anymore & I've been staring at it for hours.

Here are the sheets in question [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LgzUWSAGA2kbpar8r5nosU1bSHF7nrtvtUiHS3nB_e8/edit?usp=sharing)

Error message I'm getting is "no recipient".

I've stepped through the code as much as possible and tried to see if I can work out the fault but can't get to the bottom of it.

Here is the code:

```
for (var x = 1; x < 5; x++) { // 5 because emails are till col4

    var emailAddress = []; // Start by collecting the non-blank emails in an array

    if (getEmailFromName(row[x]) != "") {

      emailAddress.push(getEmailFromName(row[x]))

    }

  }

  emailAddress = emailAddress.join();  // Join the array to get a comma separated string

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

Here is the getEmailFromName function:

```
function getEmailFromName(sKey) {



  // to use this function, don’t put anything in the first column (A) or row (1).

  // Put the name (i.e. the key, or what we’re looking for) in column B.

  // Put what we want to return in column C. 



  var columnToSearch = 1; //column B



  // Set the active sheet to our email lookup

  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sh1 = ss1.getSheetByName("EmailContactList")

  ss1.setActiveSheet(sh1);



  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

  var line = -1;

  for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {

    if( data[i][columnToSearch] == sKey ) {

      line = i;

      break;

    }

  }



  if( line != -1 ) {

    //do what you want with the data on "line"

    return data[line][2]; //value on column C of the matched line

  } 

  else {

    return "";

  // if criteria is not found

 }

}
```

What I want to happen is it just to fire e-mails off.

Ideally I'd like to rotate the rota so the dates run down column A & the roles run across the top but I'll get to that once I can get this reliable & stable!

Comment: Is your `for loop` perhaps the cause? Try initializing `var emailAddress` above the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modified script:

- When `var emailAddress = [];` is inside of the for loop, `emailAddress` of `emailAddress = emailAddress.join()` becomes `[]`. By this, I think that such error occurs.

In order to avoid this, please modify as follows.

From:

```
for (var x = 1; x < 5; x++) { // 5 because emails are till col4
  var emailAddress = []; // Start by collecting the non-blank emails in an array
```

To:

```
var emailAddress = []; // Start by collecting the non-blank emails in an array
for (var x = 1; x < 5; x++) { // 5 because emails are till col4
```

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: My exact thoughts.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had spotted that earlier in the night but not commented stuff out properly so it was declaring it both inside & outside the For statement.

Thank you both of you :)

Comment: @Nick Francis Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.